# Reverse lookup 'QuerySet' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django

I have the following Models where I define a trucking company and their insurance company.
Models.py:

```
class Truckers(models.Model):
    DOT_Number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Address = models.CharField( max_length=200)  

class CaliIns_FK(models.Model):
    DOTNmb = models.ForeignKey(Truckers, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    CoName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

There are many truckers and not as many insurance companies. I am trying to get a list of every Trucker that has insurance.

I tried the following as per [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):

```
truck = Truckers.objects.all()
filtered = truck.caliinsfk_set.filter(truckers__isnull=True)
```

and

```
filtered = truck.caliins_fk_set.filter(truckers__isnull=True)
```

getting error:

> AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'caliinsfk_set'

Comment: `truck` here is *not* a single `truck`, but a `QuerySet` of `truck`s.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks I missed that why I was adjusting the names to make more sense for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you want `Truckers` objects with *no* related `CaliIns_FK`, you can `.filter()` your `Trucks`:

```
Truckers.objects.filter(caliins_fk__isnull=True)
```

or given the `ForeignKey` has a `related_name`, it should be:

```
Truckers.objects.filter(myrelatedname__isnull=True)
```

(with `myrelatedname` the value in `related_name` for the `ForeignKey`)
Here we thus obtain a `QuerySet` for which there is *no* related `CaliIns_FK` object.

This results in a query with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so if the "set" of related `CaliIns_FK`s is empty, it will have a row with `NULL`:

```
SELECT truckers.*
FROM truckers
LEFT OUTER JOIN caliins_fk ON truckers.DOT_Number = caliins_fk.DOTNmb_id
WHERE caliins_fk.id IS NULL
```

Note that one typically does *not* uses plural names for models, or the name of a primary key in a foreign key. According to PEP-8, attributes also are written in lowercase and with underscores. A more Django-ish approach would be:

```
class Trucker(models.Model):
    dot_number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    address = models.CharField( max_length=200)

CaliInsurance(models.Model):
    trucker = models.ForeignKey(Trucker, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

In that case the query thus looks like:

```
Trucker.objects.filter(caliinsurance__isnull=True)
```

Comment: Sorry CaliIns_FK is a class. I tried your solution but got:
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'caliins_fk' into field.

Comment: @Lev: I tried this locally, and it worked. Indeed, `CaliIns_FK` is a class, but Django creates locally a field that is the lowercase of the class name, except if you specify a `related_name`. Is `CaliIns_FK` the real class name? So it should be the lowercase of the classname, followed with `__isnull`.

Comment: @Lev:does it provide a list of options?

Comment: @Wilem: Yes it doe provide a list of options.

Comment: @Lev: what are the options?

Comment: they are all fields from class Trucker so DOT_number and Addres no foreign fields

Comment: But `CaliIns_FK` is not a `ForeignKey`, it is an "implicit" relation. It looks as if it has not loaded the second model properly. Is this defined in another app? Did you run the migrations correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184226/discussion-between-lev-and-willem-van-onsem).